# Which is the right version for Fasterflect using SNAP?

Tags: autofac

When using autofac with snap, I encounter the following exception:

Test method Halcyon.Mall.Logging.LogCallTests.FooLogCallInterceptor_ShouldBeCalled threw exception: 
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while executing a resolve operation. See the InnerException for details. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Fasterflect, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a64e1179c81b1e25' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

The autofac (2.5.2.830) is installed as a nuget package manually.
The fasterflect (2.0.4429.39723) is installed automatically as a dependent package of SNAP (1.7.3)

Comment: I am also seeing this problem. I have reverted to an earlier version of of Fasterflect using:

nuget fasterflect -Version 2.0.1.0

its a crappy workaround but its all I have right now

Comment: I'm having a problem that may or may not be related.  Fasterflect isn't strongly named, so I got the source, signed and compiled it.  Now when I try to add to another project it says it can't find it... which makes no sense to me.

Comment: I too am having the very same problem, albeit with SNAP 1.7.7 (current latest version) and StructureMap. This installs fasterflect 2.1.0, but at runtime, the ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ISampleClass>(); call from the SampleStructureMapAopConfig class throws a StructureMap 308 exception, apparently looking for fasterflect 2.0.4429.39723. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today with Snap 1.7.7 -- the latest version. Snap.StructureMap appears to require Fasterflect 2.0 but a NuGet of Snap 1.7.7 retrieves the latest Fasterflect, which is 2.1. I was able to solve it by downloading Fasterflect 2.0.2 using NuGet in a separate project (`PM> Install-Package Fasterflect -version 2.0.2`), then deleting the existing reference to Fasterflect from my main project, then browsing to and adding a file-based reference to the older Fasterflect 2.0.2 DLL.

Comment: Fasterflect versioning is causing me no end of problems as well.